# Multiple if in 1 formula

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

new user here.

can anyone show me how to get this to work in 1 formula ?
thx in advance.

Paul.

```
(if {TASKS.PRIORITY} = "1- Delivery stop" then "4"); or 
(if {TASKS.PRIORITY} = "2- Functional Some proces stop" then "12"); or
(if {TASKS.PRIORITY} = "2 - High" then "12"); or
(if {TASKS.PRIORITY} = "2- Technical Some proces stop" then "8")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
if {TASKS.PRIORITY} = "1- Delivery stop" 
then "4"
Else if {TASKS.PRIORITY} = "2- Functional Some proces stop" 
then "12"
Else if {TASKS.PRIORITY} = "2 - High" 
then "12"
Else if {TASKS.PRIORITY} = "2- Technical Some proces stop" 
then "8"
```

Comment: This is working just fine for, thank you :)
only the number is shown as string, can i t also be numeric ? 
or do i need to add another formula with tonumber or something like that ?

Comment: if you need number just give number why string representation of number.